# Mac M1: Docker compose fails in vscode - mongodb-database-tools not installable

Tags: mongodb, docker, macos, apple-m1

I'm running this Docker file in MAC M1:

## Dockerfile

```
ARG VARIANT=16-bullseye
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-${VARIANT}
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends vim wget redis-tools

ARG MONGO_CLI_VERSION=4.4
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-${MONGO_CLI_VERSION}.asc | sudo apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/${MONGO_CLI_VERSION} main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-${MONGO_CLI_VERSION}.list
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends mongodb-mongosh \
    && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-debian11-x86_64-100.5.3.deb
RUN apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-*-100.5.3.deb

RUN su node -c "wget -O ~/.git-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash"
RUN su node -c "echo -e '\n# Git Completion' >> ~/.bashrc"
RUN su node -c "echo -e 'source ~/.git-completion.bash\n' >> ~/.bashrc"
```

The response is shown in the image attached.
[image]

Comment: I noticed that in an edit, you changed the text output of your terminal window into a screenshot. Next time, consider keeping the text version (in code blocks for formatting), that makes it easier for people that help you and for search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
RUN wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-debian11-x86_64-100.5.3.deb
```

You're trying to install a package named `mongodb-database-tools-debian11-x86_64-100.5.3.deb` that is for Intel processors (x64_64) in your ARM64 image. That's not going to work.

MongoDB doesn't seem to offer a package for Debian on ARM64 on [their download page](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools). They do offer one for Ubuntu ARM64.

There doesn't seem to be a variant of `javascript-node` that builds on Ubuntu 18 Bionic, however, I think you can keep on using this Debian 11 Bullseye variant, because the version of MongoDB-database-tools for Ubuntu 16 seems to install just fine:

```
RUN wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu1604-arm64-100.5.3.deb
```

Build the image and test:

```
docker build -t test . ; docker run --rm test mongodump --version

mongodump version: 100.5.3
git version: 139703c0587796da96c367f365473d0266f9cede
Go version: go1.17.10
   os: linux
   arch: arm64
   compiler: gc
```

---

If you want this image to build on both x86 and ARM, check what architecture you're on before downloading the .deb:

```
RUN if [ "$(arch)" = "aarch64" ] || [ "$(arch)" = "arm64" ]; then\
    wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu1604-arm64-100.5.3.deb;\
  else\
    wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-debian11-x86_64-100.5.3.deb;\
  fi;
RUN apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-*-100.5.3.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another platform for example x86_64

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

> Not all images are available for ARM64 architecture. You can add
> --platform linux/amd64 to run an Intel image under emulation

Comment: The image OP is using [supports ARM64](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-vscode-devcontainers) with some limits: _"we only build arm64 architecture images that use one of the following operating systems: Debian 11 / Bullseye [...]"_.